# I have a histogram plot how to chose the appropriate point?

Tags: matlab, statistics, histogram

I had written a code to obtain a threshold pixel value of an image for imaging particles. I have got a plot attached below. I want to choose a point where there is sudden jump in the value. This will be my threshold value. I can manually do this by seeing the point. But I want to do it automatically through code what should I do?
I was thinking of sorting it and finding frequency. Then loop it to compare it with previous value. I want to know what should I choose the minimum difference to between these two values.
What other method should I use?
Here is the Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what do you mean by "sudden jump"? If I understand well, it means that there is a big difference (descrease) of pixel numbers between two adjecent gray levels. Then you can just right shift the histogram vector, and substract the two vectors, getting a vector containing the differences between two adjacent gray levels. And then, you can choose a threshold. That's all.